# Pythonic way to iterate through list of strings?

Tags: python

At the moment I have the following as a way of putting the characters in a sort of visual text-map into a dict. I am wondering though, if there's a really nice concise, pythonic way of doing this double iteration. Any ideas?

```
lines = ['abc','456','xyz']
chars = {}
for i, row in enumerate(lines):
    for j, c in enumerate(row):
        chars[i,j] = c
```

Comment: I think this is about as readable as the equivalent dictionary comprehension.

Comment: Your original code is fine!

Comment: `chars = map(list, lines)` creates a 2d list that allows to change the strings e.g., `chars[i][j] = 'c'`. You could also use `bytearray` instead of `list` here depending on how `chars` is used.

Answer (score 4):

You could express it as a dictionary comprehension:

```
chars = {(i, j): c for i, row in enumerate(lines) for j, c in enumerate(row)}
```

It's fundamentally the same iteration, only expressed a bit differently.

Comment: @freestyler: this is just fine; once you are used to the comprehensions syntax this is equally clear as the original.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm not entirely convinced, it simply crams everything on one line, by virtually the same reasoning, you could advocate using semicolons to get more on one line.

Comment: @phant0m: I think it's entirely personal preference. I agree with Martijn in that the more of a particular syntax one sees, the easier on the eye it becomes. I personally find the two versions to have about the same readability, and have no strong preference either way.

Comment: I agree with freestyler, this is less readable. OP's original code can be read line by line, left to right. The comprehensions syntax uses variables before defining them, so your eye has to jump about.

Answer (score 3):

Use a dict comprehension. The key to reading nested comprehensions:  ***"Just read them like normal loops, with the “big loop” described first and the subsequent loops nested inside of it"***  <sup>[1](http://rhodesmill.org/brandon/2009/nested-comprehensions/)</sup>

```
In [1]: lines = ['abc','456','xyz']

In [2]: {(i,j): c for i, row in enumerate(lines) for j, c in enumerate(row)}
Out[2]: 
{(0, 0): 'a',
 (0, 1): 'b',
 (0, 2): 'c',
 (1, 0): '4',
 (1, 1): '5',
 (1, 2): '6',
 (2, 0): 'x',
 (2, 1): 'y',
 (2, 2): 'z'}
```

---

You can split the comprehension to multiple lines, to make it more readable. If you *look closely* it is actually *very similar* to a regular loop, only the last line is brought to the start.

In addition to that I would recommend reading a blog post by Brandon Rhodes: ["I finally understand nested comprehensions"](http://rhodesmill.org/brandon/2009/nested-comprehensions/)

```
# Comprehension                       # Regular for loop

{(i,j):c                              # chars = {}
    for i, row in enumerate(lines)    # for i, row in enumerate(lines):
        for j, c in enumerate(row)}   #     for j, c in enumerate(row):
                                      #          chars[i,j] = c
```

Comment: This is really the same as NPE's answer.